# SQL WHERE with multiple conditions: shortcut?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to find an average temperature on days that are Saturday or Sunday using SQL. I realize a possible solution is:

```
SELECT avg(cast(meantempi as integer))
FROM weather_data
WHERE cast (strftime('%w', date) as integer) = 0 or 
      cast (strftime('%w', date) as integer) = 6
```

However, I am curious as to whether there is an optimal shortcut possible after my `WHERE` statement in this particular situation.

In other words, is there an equivalent to doing the preceding problem as:

```
SELECT avg(cast(meantempi as integer))
FROM weather_data
WHERE cast (strftime('%w', date) as integer) = 0 or 6
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (`strftime` is not standard SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
SELECT avg(cast(meantempi as integer))
FROM weather_data
WHERE cast (strftime('%w', date) as integer) IN (0, 6)
```